# How to serve content from Subfolder with htaccess

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Does anyone know if I can serve content from http://example.com/folder/public/, when a person visits http://example.com/folder/ exact file will help.

Comment: Yes, as long as there are no rules forbidding the access to this folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place this .htaccess in `/folder/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /folder/

RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*?)/?$ public/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: +1, I like your negative lookahead, hope it works for Souviiik. In this situation in the past I have often not used RewriteBase, you told be before that `RewriteBase /` helps with potential issues in document root, is this the same idea?

Comment: Thanks @zx81 Yes that is better to rely on `RewriteBase` esp. if .htaccess is in a sub folder.

Comment: Now I am getting a 500 internal server error! my site is http://subdomain.example.com/ and actual actual content is in http://subdomain.example.com/public/. I put the .htaccess suggested by you @anubhava inside subdomain folder, but it don't work!

Comment: It is pretty old answer and not for subdomain. To add a new question on existing problem I suggest it is better to open a new question with some details like your current .htaccess and your test URLs.